# Wordpress website will not load on mobile. 504 error appears

Tags: android, wordpress, performance

Recently created a wordpress website, which works fine on the following:

1. **Desktop**.
2. **iPhone on Wifi and 4G**
3. **Android on Wifi**

On Android using 4G it simply does not want to load. I receive a

> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED or HTTP ERROR 504.

I've tried optimization plugins and image resizing. Also removed a slider to see if that was the problem.  I've tried Android browser, Chrome and Firefox all to no avail.

I'm quite a novice when it comes to code, so not sure where to start. Thought I'd try here to see if anyone can offer advice?

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to supply the url..

Comment: @Noam Oops, sorry.  It's https://proudtobegreen.org

Comment: it seems to work on my device, have you tried a different carrier?

Comment: @Noam May I ask which carrier you use?

Comment: Amm, I don't think it'll help you, I guesa we're from different countries..

Comment: Oh, Im using LTE, not 4G, but I don't think it matters